# Отсутствие перевода текста под графиком изменения репутации

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, локализация, репутация, профиль-участника

Нашёл отсутствие перевода под [графиком](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=reputation&sort=graph) для выбора диапазона:

> [image: График изменения репутации]

Возможно проблема поднималась здесь, но я не нашёл :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

https://ru.traducir.win/strings/14672

Пока добавил перевод:

> Выберите диапазон, выделив область на нижнем графике

Если есть идеи получше, предлагайте в виде ответа (:

Comment: By dragging это мне кажется больше звучит выделяя, но это только мое мнение. Ваш вариант лучше чем английский)))

Comment: @Andrew в оригинале частенько странно звучащие фразы. Стараюсь локализовывать так, чтоб было удобно читать)

Answer (score 0):

Решил предложить и свой вариант:

> Для детализации выберите период на графике ниже